# how to convert multi page pdfs to jpeg images in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rmagick

I am a newbie in rails programming . I am just in the beginner stage.I want to convert multipage PDFs into jpeg images.Can any one help me out with the complete thing like tutorials.

I know we can do with Rmagick gem but dont know how to use it and where to place the code.

Comment: you are using ubantu or any other machine, beaacuse i am also do pdf to jpg in ubantu machine in rails.

Comment: i am using ubuntu machine only @Chaudhary Prakash

Comment: below answer also work properly..and also use https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/easily-extract-images-from-pdf-file/ library to convert pdf to jpg.. i hope its work proper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use docsplit gem.

**gem 'docsplit'**

Just add the above line to your gemfile, then bundle install and you can convert a pdf file to jpeg images using the code,

**Docsplit.extract_images('path/to/file',:format => [:jpeg])**

This gem require some dependencies like GraphicsMagick, Poppler to be installed on your system.

Follow the link to install dependencies and to know more about the gem,

https://documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/

Comment: This gem only extract image from pdf ,not all pdf page convert in jpg.

Comment: It will convert all pages of a pdf to the specified format.

Comment: is this single line code enough ? @TusharKhatri .i want to convert the pdf stored in **dropbox storage**  into images and save those images into same dropbox storage folder.

Comment: @santhoshkumar First you need to load the pdf from dropbox using dropbox chooser.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser

Download the file using give download url in the returned json response.

Then conver the pdf to jped images using the docsplit. And save each image or zip of each all images to dropbox using dropbox saver

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver